# Current of a circuit with regulator

Tags: current, resistors, voltage-regulator, source

When the specification of a regulator says that output is 1A for example the whole current of the circuit will be 1A?
For example I have a regulator in series with a 100Ω  resistor and a 7V source.The regulator has 5v and 1A outputs. How can I calculate the whole current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output current specification represents the *maximum* output current for that regulator.

With your example, the output current will be 5/100 = 50mA, so only 5% of the total capacity for that regulator.